# Compass Sass vs gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, sass, compass

Какие плюсы и минусы **Compass Sass** vs **gulp**?

Интересуют различия в общем виде. Например, зачем нужен Compass, когда есть Gulp, через который можно загрузить различные расширения, и scss делать, и много других операций, которые есть в Compass.

Comment: Это абсолютно разные вещи по технологиям и назначению; применительно к какой задаче рассматриваются различия между ними?

Comment: @D-side - Различия в общем виде. Например зачем нужен Compass, когда есть Gulp, через который можно загрузить различные расширения, и scss делать, и много других операций, которые есть в Compass.

Comment: @Niko_D, если вы хотите получать полезные ответы, вам стоит задавать корректные вопросы ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev  - спасибо за совет. Желаю Вам всего хорошего.

Comment: @Niko_D как тогда объясните существование `gulp-compass`?

Comment: @D-side gulp-compass -  а почему бы нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Compass](http://compass-style.org/) это **фреймворк для разработки CSS-стилей** (*CSS Authoring Framework*) на основе CSS-препроцессора **Sass**. В основе своей это просто здоровенная библиотека Sass-стилей и немного магии в форме консольной утилиты, которая среди прочего умеет ещё и собирать Sass и заниматься преобразованием графики, например, для [создания спрайтов](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/).

**Gulp** это система сборки для Node.js более-менее общего назначения. В нём нету **вообще ничего** из того, что есть в Compass. С помощью плагинов **Gulp** можно научить собирать чистый Sass (а большая часть библиотеки Compass на нём), а с помощью `gulp-compass` можно поручить **Gulp** дёргание утилиты `compass`, когда это нужно в процессе сборки, тем самым встроив в свой процесс сборки с помощью Gulp сам Compass.

С чего это вы вдруг решили их сравнивать, для меня загадка.